# How to add custom tag on EBS volume provisioned dynamically by Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to add a custom tag in PersistentVolume in EKS managed Kubernetes cluster. A custom tag is needed for my use case to manage AWS resources.  I couldn't find a way to add a tag when the volume is created. I'm looking for a method to add tag same as load balancer `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-additional-resource-tags`. Is it possible to add a tag like this and if it is, how it can be achieved?

Comment: I tried to find some hints in code on how to do it but it seems that it is not supported. You can try to write this functionality yourself or create a feature request on [kubernetes aws provisioner github issues page](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-aws/issues).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/blob/e175fe64989019e2d8f77f5a5399bad1dfd64e6b/charts/aws-ebs-csi-driver/values.yaml#L79

looks like it is supported if you use EBS